# How to change number of pictures in each row when resizing page to 450px using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml

I'm able to align all my pictures horizontally, but I'm struggling to change page's view when resizing page's size from 960px to 450px. Basically if I user shrinks page to 450px I want pictures to be shown as:

pic1  pic2  pic3

pic4  pic5  pic6

pic7 pic8   pic9

.......

........

Thank you in advance. Here's my code.

```css
body{
    width:960px;
    margin:20px auto;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:25px;
}

#letters  p{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

#letters img {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="letters">
<h3>Some pictures</h3>

<p>Pic 1<br />
<img src="./letters/a.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 2<br />
<img src="./letters/b.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 3<br />
<img src="./letters/c.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 4<br />
<img src="./letters/d.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 5<br />
<img src="./letters/e.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 6<br />
<img src="./letters/f.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 7<br />
<img src="./letters/g.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 8<br />
<img src="./letters/h.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 9<br />
<img src="./letters/i.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 10<br />
<img src="./letters/j.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 11<br />
<img src="./letters/k.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 13<br />
<img src="./letters/l.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 14<br />
<img src="./letters/m.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 15<br />
<img src="./letters/n.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 16<br />
<img src="./letters/o.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 17<br />
<img src="./letters/p.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 18<br />
<img src="./letters/q.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 19<br />
<img src="./letters/r.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 20<br />
<img src="./letters/s.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 21<br />
<img src="./letters/t.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 22<br />
<img src="./letters/u.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 23<br />
<img src="./letters/v.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 24<br />
<img src="./letters/w.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 25<br />
<img src="./letters/x.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 26<br />
<img src="./letters/y.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>

</div>
```

Comment: By the way, using <figure> for the image containers would be more semantic than <p>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `width: 960px` to `max-width: 960px` and the page will be fluid and looks like it will create rows of 3 naturally that way.

```css
body{
    max-width:960px;
    margin:20px auto;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:25px;
}

#letters  p{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

#letters img {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="letters">
<h3>Some pictures</h3>

<p>Pic 1<br />
<img src="./letters/a.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 2<br />
<img src="./letters/b.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 3<br />
<img src="./letters/c.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 4<br />
<img src="./letters/d.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 5<br />
<img src="./letters/e.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 6<br />
<img src="./letters/f.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 7<br />
<img src="./letters/g.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 8<br />
<img src="./letters/h.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 9<br />
<img src="./letters/i.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 10<br />
<img src="./letters/j.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 11<br />
<img src="./letters/k.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 13<br />
<img src="./letters/l.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 14<br />
<img src="./letters/m.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 15<br />
<img src="./letters/n.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 16<br />
<img src="./letters/o.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 17<br />
<img src="./letters/p.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 18<br />
<img src="./letters/q.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 19<br />
<img src="./letters/r.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 20<br />
<img src="./letters/s.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 21<br />
<img src="./letters/t.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 22<br />
<img src="./letters/u.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 23<br />
<img src="./letters/v.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 24<br />
<img src="./letters/w.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 25<br />
<img src="./letters/x.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>
<p>Pic 26<br />
<img src="./letters/y.png" width="100" height="100" />
</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!. One quick question. How can I show 7 pictures for each row?

Comment: @progx anywhere between around `max-width: 860px` and `max-width: 970px`

Comment: got it!. Thanks!